# Permission denied (publickey) when try to connect to github with custom key file

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I have created `~/.ssh/config` file with:

```
Host github.com-xxx
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_xxx
```

When I run `ssh github.com-xxx` I'm getting error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

(And I have other `~/.ssh/id_rsa` files defined for other server as well.)

When I add `-v` the log looks like:

```
    OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
    debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/xxx/.ssh/config
    debug1: /Users/xxx/.ssh/config line 17: Applying options for github.com-xxx
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
    debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.113] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa_xxx type 1
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa_xxx-cert type -1
    debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh_0.7.0
    debug1: no match: libssh_0.7.0
    debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
    debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
    debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /Users/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa_xxx
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
    Permission denied (publickey).
```

When I just try to `ssh git@github.com` it succeeds with:

```
Hi OTHER_USER! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
```

The `OTHER_USER` is the user I created the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file.

Comment: yes,it's just for tests if because I'm trying so set up the ~/.ssh/config file but I failed so far

Comment: Why? I can succesfully ssh for some other user - see the edited question.

Comment: this is the method to test ssh connection to github: https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/